# Is this garbage-collected or not?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

Here is some code:

```
public class A {
  private volatile B b;

  public void methodC() {
    b.doSomething();
  }

  public void setB(B newB) {
    this.b = newB;
  }
}
```

'Thread 1' is executing b.doSomething() by executing methodC().

At the same time 'thread 2' set a new B object into 'b'.

My question is:

Could the object previously refereced by 'b' be garbage-collected although doSomething() method on it is still executing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because in order to call a member function you need to have a reference to the object. Therefore the thread which is calling `b.doSomething()` will be holding a reference thus preventing garbage collection.

*Although check Jon Harrop's answer below for a situation when `b` could be `GC`'d.*

Comment: I think there is no direct or derived reference to the previous referenced object from 'thread 1'. I thought 'reachable' in GC document means there must be some thread having any direct or derived refernce to it.

Comment: Any reference I can be certain?

Comment: There must be a reference to the object in the thread's stack in order for the member function to be called. How else can this function be called?

Comment: Have a look at the `StackFrame` class which represents a single frame on the thread's stack. It holds a reference to the `this` object.

Comment: You're right. I found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object I misunderstood reachability in GC. I thought all reachability comes from variables not call stack. Thanks for the detail :-)

Comment: -1 Although members are typically passed the `this` pointer there is no requirement for it to be kept reachable unnecessarily so this answer is wrong.#

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying @JonHarrop. Could you provide more detail and how it relates to the question?

Comment: You're saying that the answer to the question is "no it cannot be collected" because the member must be keeping the object reachable via its `this` pointer when, in fact, that is not necessarily true and the correct answer is "it may be collected".

Answer (score 1):

> Could the object previously refereced by 'b' be garbage-collected although doSomething() method on it is still executing?

Yes, the object previously refereced by 'b' might be garbage-collected even though the `doSomething()` method on it is still executing.

You might expect `this` to be reachable while one of its methods is being executed because methods are implicitly passed the `this` pointer and you might assume that it is always spilled to the stack. However, many optimizations can alter this and remove `this` from the set of global roots seen by the GC.

For example, if the body of the `doSomething` method ends with code that does not require `this` and the method is inlined then `this` might not be spilled from a register to the stack or its stack slot might be overwritten. In either case, the GC will no longer see `this` even though execution is still inside `doSomething` and, therefore, `this` might be garbage collected.

Comment: +1 Ah, I see what you mean now. I guess I was thinking that the `this` pointer would get used within `doSomething` but you're right - if there's no reference to `this` within that function then there's nothing to stop it being GC'd.

Comment: Exactly. Even if it is used it could still be reclaimed after the last use inside the `doSomething` function.